# Something hit the back of the computer screen

Tags: display, colors, desktop

I am not entirely sure what is wrong with the display. My lamp hit the back of my screen and it has been acting strange since. It was working fine just a couple of hours ago. i have attached some pictures.

[image: background picture]

[image: browser picture]

Here is a picture i took from my phone
[image: Phone picture of desktop]

This is another picture from my phone
[image: Another picture from my phone]

If you compare the picture from the video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DaH4W1rY9us)
to the picture above, you can tell that it is different. The background is supposed to be pure black.

Also how can physical damage from the back affect the screen? It is also a touch screen desktop

Comment: I'm not seeing anything in the attached pictures. Does it look different if you photograph the screen?

Comment: Nothing appears wrong with the screenshots. That would make sense since it's likely physical damage which will not show up in a screenshot. In that case you have your answer: replace the screen :(

Comment: This is another picture from my phone
[Another picture from my phone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i1Kt2.jpg) Blaine, you are correct. If you compare the picture from the video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DaH4W1rY9us)
to the picture above, you can tell that it is different. The background is supposed to be pure black.

Comment: You really should be editing the original question - not posting answers. You should always be able to edit your own posts. You might want to look at the [help] and [tour]

Answer (score 0):

Let me preface this by saying I don't think you will be able to get a definitive answer here based on the symptoms.  My input is pretty much diagnostic advice, speculation and opinion, and as such, I hate to post it as an answer.  But it's way too long for comments and it could be helpful.  If it gets feedback that it's inappropriate, I'll delete it.

1. **Rule out other things**

   It was the monitor that got hit, but there's a chance that the bump or ensuing chaos actually affected something else to cause the symptoms.  Those things can be checked easily and "non-invasively" to rule them out.

   **Computer:** Connect another monitor just to rule out the possibility that the issue is actually in the computer rather than the monitor.  If you don't have an old one sitting around, borrow one, or take your computer to a friend's house (or your office) and connect it to their monitor.  Similarly, connect your monitor to another computer.

   **Cable:** Also, rule out a problem with the video cable.  Borrow or buy a cheap one to test, or if you do this at a friend's house and their monitor uses the same type of cable, connect your monitor using their cable and their monitor using your cable.

   The symptom is associated with whatever is the damaged component and the problem will move with that component when you swap things.
2. **Monitor**

   If you verify that the issue is inside your monitor, my guess would be a couple of potential problems.  It doesn't seem likely that an impact would damage components.  The more likely result would be disturbing an electrical connection.

   **Ribbon Cable:** If you're lucky, it's a ribbon cable connection.  Inside the monitor, there are a bunch of things connected by ribbon cables.  They are hard to disturb by just an impact to the case (they're subjected to worse bumps in shipping), but again, they're easy to check and fix or rule out.

   Disconnect the monitor from the power and your computer and open its case.  It may be held together with obvious screws.  If not, and it isn't obvious how the case comes apart, look online for YouTube videos.

   Look for any ribbon cable that looks like it isn't fully seated or is cockeyed to the connector.  If you find one, reseat it.

   The inside may have several layers, and screen connectors may be hidden behind a circuit board, so some amount of internal disassembly may be required.  Keep track of how things come apart and what parts go where.  It will look obvious while you're taking it apart, but it will be much less so once you have a collection of separate components, screws, and other pieces.

   If you don't see any disturbed ribbon cable connections, I probably would not prophylactically reseat every one; the chance of those being the problem is small and there is a risk of causing damage, yourself, if you're not familiar with electronics assembly or repair.

   **Solder Joint:** Another possibility is a bad solder joint that could have been jarred over the edge by the impact.  You can use a lighted magnifier to look for suspicious connections, but it is likely to require test equipment and schematics.  If you find one, it will be difficult to resolder if you aren't skilled at micro-soldering and have the right tools.

   If you do find a suspicious looking joint, you may be able to verify it by gently wiggling it with a pencil eraser while looking at the image in a mirror (to see the screen while at the back of the monitor).  If you definitively identify a bad solder joint and don't have the skill or tools to fix it yourself, someone you know who does a lot of electronics work may be able to resolder it for you.

   Of course recognize that it generally isn't a good idea to poke around inside with the power on if you don't know what you're doing.  You can damage the unit and/or yourself.  The monitor should be disconnected from the power and your computer while you're disassembling and assembling.  Connect it only during testing.  It's also a good idea to wear latex or lightweight cotton gloves to protect yourself while poking around with the power on.
3. **Professional Repair**

   Unless you have a relatively new and high-end monitor, you may not find it cost effective to have it professionally repaired.  You can buy new monitors starting in the price range of the typical repair cost.  For a high-end model, the repair cost could be a substantial down payment on a better monitor, with a full remaining service life, and a long warranty.

   If yours is an older monitor, replacement parts may be reconditioned ones. Those are only as good as the reconditioning job and carry a short warranty.  Even with new parts, repair jobs are usually warrantied for only 30 to 90 days.

   You may have to pay a non-trivial diagnostic fee, with a good chance of then learning that it isn't worth the repair cost.  However, some models are often serviced locally by just swapping out one of the few major internal components.  Your old parts are sent off to a dedicated repair center to become the reconditioned parts for someone else.  In that case, the shop may have a fixed price that covers your repair that they can tell you up front.

   Only you can decide on what is the best course of action, but those are some aspects to inquire about if you take it to the shop.